# How to bring `npm` back?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm-install

I installed `nodejs` via `nvm` on `Ubuntu` server, and found issues with jenkins tasks. So I uninstalled `nvm`, and reinstalled `nodejs` by

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl --silent --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

And now on my `Ubuntu` server, the `node` is back but `npm` wasn't, how to reinstall `npm`?

This is my command echo back:
    $ node -v
    5.8.0

```
$ npm -v
-bash: /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v5.8.0/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall npm
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.